# How to sum each row without using sum function and numpy just using for loops and if

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

How to sum each row of the 2D matrix using for loops and if statements and then print the result of the sum with the maximum value and its row index as the result?

```py
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

Max=0
index=0

for i in range(2):
    total=0 
    for j in range(3):
        if total>Max:
            Max=total
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to find a way of adding up the numbers in a single list (i.e. your own implementation of `sum`)? Also you can start using `sum` and try to solve the rest of the problem _assuming_ you already have that function. You replace it by your own once you have it. Don't try to solve everything at once.

Comment: I know, sum function is easier but it is my project and i have to solve it just with for loops. So anyone can help me with this? I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "How can i sum each row 2d_array using for loop and if then print the maximum one with it index as a result?" **This is two separate things**. Please try thinking about one at a time. We certainly require the *question* to be about only one; please see [ask].

Comment: "t is my project and i have to solve it just with for loops" What exactly does this mean? Did someone else give you this requirement? If so, please also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Answer (score 1):

Meh, this is a piece of cake:

```
A = [[1,2,3], 
     [4,5,6],
     [4,4,9],
     [4,7,2]]

Max=0
index=0
 
for i in range(len(A)):
    total=0 
    for x in A[i]:
        total += x
    if total > Max:
        Max=total
        index = i
print(Max, index) #here you gets (17, 2)
```

Comment: The nested loop can be simplified to:      
    **for x in A[i]:
        total += x**

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score -2):

> How to sum each row without using sum function and numpy just using for loops and if

Ok so you have a Matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns. You want to get the total sum of all the elements of each row (3 elements per row since you have 3 columns) and without using `sum` or `numpy`. Finally you want to display the index of the row that had the greater sum value (since we have 2 rows the index can be 0 or 1).

> How can I sum each row of the 2D matrix using `for` loops and `if` statements and then print the result of the sum with the maximum value and its index as a result?

Based on your restrictions and what I believe you want to accomplish here is a posible answer:

```py
A=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
Max = 0 
index = 0

for i in range(2):
    total = 0
    for j in range(3):
        total += A[i][j]
        if total>Max:
            Max=total
            index=i

print(Max, index)
```

The code is pretty similar to your attempt where `i` is the index of the current row and `j` the index of the current column.

1. The variable `total` will hold the result of the sum (resetting to 0 after each row).
2. The conditional `if` will update the values of `Max` and `index` only when it finds a row sum that is greater than the previous ones, ultimately finding the largest one.